# Identifying the delta between two graph images

Tags: neo4j, node-neo4j

How we can identify the differnece between two nodes in Neo4j from time to time.In other words i have two graph images and my task is to identify the delta between these two..

Any suggestions?

Here i will have access to a neo4j DB which will be updating by an application to whcih i dont have accesss.And my job is to identify the changes done to DB with in a time interval like for 4 hours once etc..here nodes doesn't have any time stamps. Previously i reffered as two images since my requirement is to identify the changes happened to the same DB with in some time gap.ex 1 pm( one graph intance) to 4 pm(second graph instance) with 4 hours time interval..

Hope my query is clear..

Thanks..

Comment: What do you mean by *graph images*? Are you referring to the properties contained in two nodes? Or are you referring to the differences between two complete Neo4j graphs? Or... are you referring to an actual *image* (e.g. jpg or png)? It would be helpful if you updated your question accordingly. As it stands, it's hard to figure out what, exactly, you're asking.

Comment: Hi David..i have updated the question..